# HTML CODE of the slider .When double click on the arrow then it change the image instead of single click

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML CODE of the slider .When double click on the arrow then it change the image instead of single click. The code is not working properly tried a lot on it but not working.**

```
<body>
<button id="l" onClick="myf()"><b><</b></button>

<img  id="a" src="im1.jpg">

<button id="r" onClick="my()"><b>></b></button>
</body>
```

**Java Script Code of the slider**

```
<script>
var aa=["im1.jpg","im2.jpg","im3.jpg","im4.jpg","im5.jpg","im6.jpg"];
var ab=0;
function my()
{
if(ab<aa.length)
{
document.getElementById("a").src=aa[ab];
ab++;
}
} 

function myf()
{
if(ab>0)
{
ab--;
document.getElementById("a").src=aa[ab];
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: code is looking fine

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I guess OP means `double click`

Comment: You need to specify a clear question. What do you intend to do and what error do you get?

Comment: The image is changed on double clicking on the button. But image is not changing on single click on the button. I tried a lot to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ondblclick Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp)

```
<body>
    <button id="l" ondblclick="myf()"><b><</b></button>

    <img  id="a" src="im1.jpg">

    <button id="r" ondblclick="my()"><b>></b></button>
</body>
```